# awk: replace a character on a given line and column if it doesn't match a character on the same given column in the first line

Tags: text-processing, awk

I've tried for ages and I haven't even gotten close. Using awk, how do I: replace every '*' with '-' on every line > 1 in every column, but only if the corresponding column in line 1 is not an '*'?

Example input:
`a|s|d|f|g|*|A|*|*|g|c|a|*|A|*`
`a|*|*|f|g|*|*|*|*|g|c|a|*|A|*`
`*|s|*|f|g|*|a|t|*|g|c|a|*|A|*`
`a|s|d|*|g|*|T|*|C|g|c|a|a|A|T`

Example output
`a|s|d|f|g|*|A|*|*|g|c|a|*|A|*`
`a|-|-|f|g|*|-|*|*|g|c|a|*|A|*`
`-|s|-|f|g|*|a|t|*|g|c|a|*|A|*`
`a|s|d|-|g|*|T|*|C|g|c|a|a|A|T`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line of headers needs to be scanned to find all "not *".
That a column "has not" an `*` could be stored in an array `a[]`.
For all next lines, only the columns that exist in `a[]` **may** need change.

That could be implemented as:

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
           NR==1 {
                   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if( $i != "*" ) a[i]
                 } 
           NR>1  {
                   for(i in a)        if( $i == "*" ) $i="-"
                 } 
           1
          ' file

a|s|d|f|g|*|A|*|*|g|c|a|*|A|*
a|-|-|f|g|*|-|*|*|g|c|a|*|A|*
-|s|-|f|g|*|a|t|*|g|c|a|*|A|*
a|s|d|-|g|*|T|*|C|g|c|a|a|A|T
```

This implements the least amount of changes needed. It should be the fastest.

Comment: Yup, that's how you do it - nice solution!

Answer (score 4):

One possible way (may not be the best)

```
awk -F'|' '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS} 
  NR==1 {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="*") a[i]
  } 
  {
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="*" && !(i in a)) $i="-"
  } 
  1
' file
a|s|d|f|g|*|A|*|*|g|c|a|*|A|*
a|-|-|f|g|*|-|*|*|g|c|a|*|A|*
-|s|-|f|g|*|a|t|*|g|c|a|*|A|*
a|s|d|-|g|*|T|*|C|g|c|a|a|A|T
```